# Installation problem: couldn't find XML in the pack

Tags: joomla, installation, sifr

I'm a beginner in Joomla CMS, and maybe the answer is obvious.

I've downloaded the lastest released version of sIFR 2.0.7. When I try to install the plugin on my Joomla site through the wizard, it tells me that the package doesn't contain an XML install file. I've opened the .zip archive and I couldn't find it either, as the installer wizard told me.

Maybe I'm missing something, but how can I install the package ? Is there any requirement ?

Regards,

Yoann

P.S: sorry if my english is bad, I'm french :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not download sIFR-2.0.7.zip and expect it to load like a Joomla plug-in. You must get sIFR from here [Joomla sIFR](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/typography/5540). This will load without any problems, since it is designed to be a Joomla 1.5+ addon. The name of the file you get is `bot_sifr_v2.0.7_J15.zip`.

In order to get everything running, you will respond according to this message:

```
Loads sIFR inside joomla, place the following code at the bottom of your template (just before </body></html>) to make it work:

<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof sIFR == "function"){
  sIFR.replaceElement(".contentheading, .componentheading", named(
    {sFlashSrc: "plugins/system/bot_sifr/tradegothic.swf", sColor: "#c64934", sWmode: "transparent"}
  ));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works fine now :)

But, what is sIFR-2.0.7.zip ? Is it a addon for standard web developpment ( without Joomla ) ?